# Ethernet devices polarity reversal support

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, polarity, phy

Does all Ethernet PHY devices support polarity reversal even if its not mentioned in the datasheet?
[I mean polarity reversal by swapping TX+ with TX- (Like connecting TX+ to RX- or TX- to RX+).

Is there any IEEE standard that dictates that all Ethernet devices that must be able to support polarity reversal? If so, can you please provide your reference?

Comment: Just to be sure, you really mean polarity reversal by swapping TX+ with TX- for example, and not about swapping TX pair with RX pair? And for which all possible Ethernet standards? Have you tried to read the standards to find this information?

Comment: Yes, I mean polarity reversal by swapping TX+ with TX- (Like connecting TX+ to RX- or TX- to RX+). I am not sure which standard supports this? Can someone tell me what's the IEEE standard that mentions this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no 802.3 series standards that mandate it. There may be some other standards, say industrial or automotive Ethernet, that may mandate such functionality - but those are specific application areas, nothing general.

Polarity reversal isn’t really something that has to be dealt with routinely. It’s a wiring error and should be corrected - not the NIC’s job. MDIX, on the other hand, is a common requirement since nobody cares anymore about straight-through vs. crossover patch cables. But those cables still must preserve polarity and when they don’t, things may or may not work well.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE Std 802.3ab-1999 says the following in section 40.1.4 "Signaling":

> 1000BASE-T signaling is performed by the PCS generating continuous code-group sequences that the PMA
> transmits over each wire pair. The signaling scheme achieves a number of objectives including
>
> ...
>
> j) Ability to automatically detect and correct for pair swapping and unexpected crossover connections.
>
> k) Ability to automatically detect and correct for incorrect polarity in the connections.
>
> ...

So Gigabit Ethernet directly mandates auto detection and correction of reverse polarity.

As for 100BASE-TX, the polarity doesn't matter, since this standard is using MLT-3 as it's encoding method.

Finally, for 10BASE-T, I couldn't find a direct mention of this in the standard. However, in an [application note](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/AN127-UNG.pdf) from Micrel (now Microchip), the following is stated:

> This is the only failure mechanism out of the three
> that is addressed by the IEEE 802.3 specification.
> Reverse polarity of the transmit or receive pairs can
> only cause a potential problem for 10BASE-T links, as
> 100BASE-TX Fast Ethernet does not actually use the
> polarity in its receiver. For 10BASE-T links the IEEE
> 802.3 requires the Ethernet PHY to support autopolarity detection and correction of the received data.
> Reverse polarity can be easily detected through either
> link pulses or SOI (start of idle) of the 10BASE-T data
> and corrected. In fact it was very common in the past
> to incorrectly wire the polarity of the data pairs to
> ease any PCB layout issues.

To summarise, if the excerpt from the application note is to be believed, all Ethernet PHY that works with twisted pairs is mandated to support auto polarity detection and correction.
However, I've often heard that you can only be sure of this if you're using Gigabit Ethernet.
In the end, it's good practice to consider reversed polarity within a pair a wiring error, even if it won't cause any problems.